# How to find all the paths to a particular node to leaf node and also the preceding nodes from python dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary `fname` (`fname` serves as the key), parent and child node associated with each node (dictionary reference in code). I will input one key (For following piece of code B is the key- i.e fname :`['B']`). I have to keep parent node into consideration. For B I want paths as `[A,B,C,C1,X],[A,B,C,C2],[A,B,D,D1],[A,B,D,D2],[R1,B,C,C1,X],[R,B,C,C2],[R1,B,D,D1],[R2,B,D,D2],[R1,B,P]`.

I tried to find the leaf nodes, but i am not getting any output for the following piece of code.

```
def neighbor_find(graph, key, neighbor, current_path, paths_list):
    for v in range(0,len(graph)-1):  #access the values in list 
        if d[v]['fname'] == key: #checks if the key input is present in the list
            if not d[v][neighbor]: #if not the path is appended as it is
                paths_list.append(current_path)
            else: # if key present in list, checks its parent/child 
                for node in d[v][neighbor]:
                    for i in range(0,len(d[v]['parent'])):
                        print(d[v]['parent'][i]['name'])
                    neighbor_find(graph, node, neighbor, [node] + current_path, paths_list)


def path_find(graph, key, path_list):
    parents_list, children_list = [], []
    neighbor_find(graph, key, 'parent', [], parents_list) 
    neighbor_find(graph, key, 'child', [], children_list)

    for parent_path in parents_list:
        for children_path in children_list:
            path_list.append(parent_path + [key] + children_path[::-1])
    for i in range (0,len(path_list)):
        print("path" ,i+1 , ":", path_list[i])


d = [
     {
          'file' : 'user_auth.py',
          'fname': 'B',
          'parent': [{'name': 'A','filename': 'user_auth.py'},{'name': 'R1','filename': 'user_registration.py'}],
          'child': [{'name': ['C', 'D'], 'filename' : 'user_auth.py'}],
          'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']        
     },
     { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
         'fname': 'C',
         'parent': [{'name': ['B', 'M'], 'filename': 'user_auth.py'}],
         'child': [{'name':['C1', 'C2'], 'filename' : 'user_auth.py' }],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_004']
     },
      { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
        'fname': 'D',
         'parent': [{'name': 'B' , 'filename' : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'child': [{'name':['D1', 'D2'], 'filename' : 'user_auth.py' }],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_002']
      },
     { 'file' : 'out.js',
        'fname': 'C1',
         'parent': [{'name':'C', 'filename' : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'child': [{'name': 'X', 'filename' : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
     },
      { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
        'fname': 'M',
         'parent': [],
         'child': [{'name': 'C', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} , { 'name' : 'N' , 'filename' : 'user_registration.py'}],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_UI_003']
      },
     { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
        'fname': 'A',
         'parent': [],
         'child': [{'name': 'B', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_005']
      },
      {'file' : 'user_registration.py',
        'fname': 'N',
         'parent': [{'name': 'M', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'child': [],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
      },
      {'file' : 'user_auth.py',
        'fname': 'D1',
         'parent': [{'name': 'D', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
         'child': [],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
         },
      { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
        'fname': 'D2',
         'parent': [{'name': 'D', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'}],
         'child': [],
         'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
     },
      { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
          'fname': 'C2',
          'parent': [{'name': 'C', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
          'child': [],
          'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
      },
      { 'file': 'user_auth.py',
       'fname': 'X',
          'parent': [{'name': 'C1', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
          'child': [],
          'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
      },
     { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
           'fname' :  'B',
           'parent' : [{'name': 'R1', 'filename'  : 'user_registration.py'} ],
           'child' : [{'name': 'P', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
           'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
            },
     { 'file' : 'user_registration.py',
          'fname' : 'R1',
           'parent' : [],
           'child' : [{'name': 'B', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
           'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
            },
     { 'file' : 'user_auth.py',
          'fname' : 'P',
           'parent' : [{'name': 'B', 'filename'  : 'user_auth.py'} ],
           'child' : [],
           'tags': ['TC_HRM_API_001','TC_HRM_API_002','TC_HRM_UI_003']
            }]

key = 'B'

path_list = []
path_find(d, key, path_list)
```

Expected output is :`[A,B,C,C1,X],[A,B,C,C2],[A,B,D,D1],[A,B,D,D2],[R1,B,C,C1,X],[R,B,C,C2],[R1,B,D,D1],[R2,B,D,D2],[R1,B,P]`
actual output is: `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can split this problem into:

1. find all the paths from `current node` to `parent` (root)
2. find all the paths from `current node` to `child` (leaf)
3. concat all `parents` paths and `chilren` paths together like `product`.

So the main problem in your code is that you only traverse the children, you can try the idea above by `dfs`:

```
def neighbor_find(graph, key, neighbor, current_path, paths_list):
    for v in graph.values():
        if v['fname'] == [key]:
            if not v[neighbor]:
                paths_list.append(current_path)
            else:
                for node in v[neighbor]:
                    neighbor_find(graph, node, neighbor, [node] + current_path, paths_list)


def path_find(graph, key, path_list):
    parents_list, children_list = [], []
    neighbor_find(graph, key, 'parent', [], parents_list)
    neighbor_find(graph, key, 'child', [], children_list)

    for parent_path in parents_list:
        for children_path in children_list:
            path_list.append(parent_path + [key] + children_path[::-1])
```

test code:

```
d = {1: {'fname': ['B'],
         'parent': ['A'],
         'child': ['C', 'D']},
     2: {'fname': ['C'],
         'parent': ['B', 'M'],
         'child': ['C1', 'C2']},
     3: {'fname': ['D'],
         'parent': ['B'],
         'child': ['D1', 'D2']},
     4: {'fname': ['C1'],
         'parent': ['C'],
         'child': ['X']},
     5: {'fname': ['M'],
         'parent': [],
         'child': ['C', 'N']},
     6: {'fname': ['A'],
         'parent': [],
         'child': ['B']},
     7: {'fname': ['N'],
         'parent': ['M'],
         'child': []},
     8: {'fname': ['D1'],
         'parent': ['D'],
         'child': []},
     9: {'fname': ['D2'],
         'parent': ['D'],
         'child': []},
     10: {'fname': ['C2'],
          'parent': ['C'],
          'child': []},
     11: {'fname': ['X'],
          'parent': ['C'],
          'child': []},
     }
key = 'C'

path_list = []
path_find(d, key, path_list)

print(path_list)
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'C1', 'X'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C2'], ['M', 'C', 'C1', 'X'], ['M', 'C', 'C2']]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: glad to help you. I think you can give a complete test data next time.  if not, we can not test our code @sharayusalunkhe

Comment: Sure, if i find any difficulty with the complete data set will seek your help. Thanks a lot again. @recnac

Comment: can you help me with the update question i.e. the data structure is updated

Comment: which one?@sharayusalunkhe

Comment: I have updated the above question. can you please check that @recnac

Comment: don't understand, why no ABP in result? and why don't you add R1 and P in to exist B' s data

Comment: I think you just change the input data, and has no effect on algorithm, it is just because of wrong input.

Comment: that output was for a particular part. as a whole the algorithm doesn't give me the desired output since the data structure is changed if you take a look @recnac

Comment: I think you can deal with the input/ouput to adapt to the algorithm